# How to paste a character with Microsoft Keyboard Macro system?

Tags: keyboard, macros

I have a SideWinder X4 keyboard, and it supports the awesome `Mouse and Keyboard Center` app.

I write a lot of location-based text/code, and frequently have to open the `Character Map` app, find the degrees symbol ° , copy, and paste into whatever I'm doing.

How do I just make a macro to paste in this single character when I smash the appropriate key?

Comment: If you select United States International as keyboard layout, you can hit `alt gr`+`shift`+`;` to type a °. (alt gr, is the right alt)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LPChip, I figured out

```
On your keyboard, press Alt + 0176.

Note: This method works only for keyboards that include a 10-key numeric pad.
```

So I set up the macro to press these keys.

Comment: Even though that is not what I meant, it is another way to do it. I basically have 2 keyboard languages installed. United States and United States International. I can switch between them by pressing Left-Alt + Left-Shift. In United States International, I can easily type these by holding the right alt: `äåéþüúíóö«»áßðø¶´©ñµç¿¡²³¤€¼½¾‘’°¨Ç¿¹¥×÷¦¬` and if I did not had some software installed, I would have even more keys. :)